# Jupyter Notebook не подсвечивает match-case

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.10

Как можно добавить подсветку ключевых слов для *Jupyter Notebook*? Сами по себе *match-case* выражения хорошо работают, но без подсветки не очень комфортно.

Поставил все последние апдейты, но ничего не изменилось.

```
python                       3.10.4

jupyter-client               7.3.1
jupyter-core                 4.10.0
jupyter-server               1.17.0
jupyterlab                   3.4.2
jupyterlab-pygments          0.2.2
jupyterlab-server            2.13.0
```

**Вот как это выглядит в *Jupyter*:**

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

*Буду благодарен за помощь, возможно это поможет еще кому-то кроме меня.*

**UPD:** Появилась еще одна [поблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415949/) с *match-case* в *Jupyter Notebook*

Comment: Написать issue в репозитории Jupyter Notebook на гитхабе, чтобы добавили подсветку.

Comment: @insolor, я уже месяц назад написал :)

Хотел просто сам себе подсветку замутить