# Проблемы с проверкой типов match-case в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.10

Обычно, когда я хочу проверить тип, я делаю так:

```py
for x in ([], {}):
    match x:
        case list(_):
            print('[OUTPUT] Do something with list')
        case dict(_):
            print('[OUTPUT] Do something with dict')
```

В *IDLE Shell* все работает, а в *Jupyter Notebook* лезет ошибка, вот полный output выполнения кода:

```py
[OUTPUT] Do something with list

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [74], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for x in ([], {}):
      2     match x:
      3         case list(_):
      4             print('[OUTPUT] Do something with list')
----> 5         case dict(_):
      6             print('[OUTPUT] Do something with dict')

TypeError: called match pattern must be a type
```

Проблем с версиями *python* и *jupyterlab* нет, я проверял.

```
python                       3.10.4

jupyter-client               7.3.1
jupyter-core                 4.10.0
jupyter-server               1.17.0
jupyterlab                   3.4.2
jupyterlab-pygments          0.2.2
jupyterlab-server            2.13.0
```

Возможно ли пофиксить это?
У меня была еще одна [проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415468/) с *match-case* в *Jupyter Notebook*, если кому интересно.
Если нужны скриншоты, я отправлю.

**UPD:** *НЕЛЬЗЯ* убирать скобки после `dict`, это приведет к тому, что *Python* воспримет `dict` как переменную, и запишет туда текущее значение кейса. Проблема именно в самом *Jupyter*, что можно понять из вопроса, который был о фиксе *jupyter*-а, а не о проблемах в моем коде (которых нет).

Comment: По идее Jupyter не должен влиять на выполнение кода, могут влиять разные версии Python. Попробуйте обновиться до 3.10.5, и удостоверьтесь, что в Jupyter Notebook используется та же версия (сделайте `import sys; print(sys.version)`).

Comment: Я удалил ваших маслят, рекомендую ознакомиться с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 2):

Вот измененный код:

```py
for x in ([], {}):
    match x:
        case list():
            print('[OUTPUT] Do something with list')
        case dict():
            print('[OUTPUT] Do something with dict')
```

Проверил, у меня в Jupyter работает и выводит:

```
[OUTPUT] Do something with list
[OUTPUT] Do something with dict
```

*PS: Лусиану Ромальо в своей книге "Python: К вершинам мастерства" делает это также.*

Comment: Я проверял - у меня все работает нормально и в IDLE и в Jupyter. Версия Python - 3.10.5

Comment: У меня тоже Python 3.10.5:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy702.png

Comment: Ой, ошибся - правда два раза выводит. Попробую сделать что-нибудь с кодом.

Comment: Вот, изменил код - теперь действительно работает.

Comment: Да, похоже, что так работает.

Comment: @insolor, так Вы Jupyter себе поставьте с начала, это только там не работает.

@VladimirChistov, Вы похоже плохо знаете Python, у меня была запись `case dict(_)`, в данном случае, `_` это переменная, в которую попадает значение текущего кейса, там могут быть более сложные штуки, чем я привел.

Comment: Еще раз говорю, проблема не в моем коде, а в Jupyter, на который я хочу накатить патч

Comment: @Gnifajio, так вы проверили в Jypyter, что у вас та же версия python, что в IDLE, как я в комменте к вопросу писал? Если проверили, приведите скриншоты.

Comment: @insolor, я сейчас начну с Вами ругаться. Я в вопросе указал версию Python и Jupyter. Как можно было не заметить...

Comment: @Gnifajio вы в вопросе вывод чего-то, что показало версию где-то. Чтобы 100% быть уверенным, что версии одинаковы в IDLE и в Jupyter, нужено смотреть вывод sys.version именно в IDLE и вывод в Jupyter. А дальше уже писать issue на гитхабе к проекту jupyter, если версии действительно одинаковые.

Comment: @insolor, я так и делал, а Ваше тугодумие тратит наше с Вами время :: [чтобы 100% быть уверенным](https://i.imgur.com/ZDG7dAv.png)

Comment: @Gnifajio отлично, теперь идите и пишите issue. Я все-таки советую почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct, потому что ваше отношение к другим участникам когда-нибудь доведет вас до бана.

Comment: @insolor, я уже 28 дней назад это сделал, а они не шевелятся. Хочу сам патч накатить, а куда - не знаю.

Comment: @Gnifajio, смотрите исходники jupyter и разбирайтесь